# unloading data from oracle dbf files

Tags: oracle, restore

I have a list of oracle dbf files and I need to restore the information inside these files, there are no control files and anything else. only DBF file 
http://s9.postimg.org/mxmx0g73j/Untitled.jpg

Is there any parsing tool or recovery tool that can open DBF files and unload the information in it..

Comment: I've re-opened this question because it was closed as the duplicate of a question that was later deleted as not a real question. See [this meta discussion for more details](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/closed-topic-leads-to-non-existant-topic).

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 alternatives:

- create a new controlfile and try to add those file in one or more tablespaces, they look part of a partitioned object (you might want to use dbverify before running create controlfile)
- use UNIX strings command, this should recover some information, but not all...
- use the BBED tool as documented here:
  http://orafaq.com/papers/dissassembling_the_data_block.pdf
  this is a powerful tool but takes a bit of time to master

Also, if you have Oracle Support contract you might try contacting them, it is their format, 
it is the easiest path to "success".. but probably the most expensive.

Comment: if you would please clarify the first option, or give me a link to tutorial or something, BBED or any Data unloading tools will be the last resort

Answer (score 2):

1. which files do you have?
2. which version of Oracle database did they belong to?
3. how were they backed up?
4. what kind of data would you like to read? (text or also numeric/date formats?)
5. what do you already know about the data you are looking for?
6. how did you get these files in your possession?
7. what volume of data do you expect to have to read/recover?

If the files happen to be from a valid backup you could have some luck, but mostly because you could turn in into a running database again. The complete system tablespace should be among the files you have to make a chance.

Only reading data from the bare dbf files .... there are many options that make this hard to do. Depending on what you know about what you are looking for makes this more or less possible. Start with: forget it and be happy with any word you can recover this way.

dd and od might be your friends, compression and encryption not.

Maybe Kurt can help you, see [dude](http://www.ora600.nl/DUDE_PRIMER.pdf) could be your best option.